# Chrome extension run background script and then content script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

On browser action clicked I execute my injection script which injects few nested divs

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    file: 'src/injection.js'
});
```

before I click browser action my content script runs and doesn't work as it should, because divs, that are injected on browser action, are missing. Is there any solution to reload content script without reloading page?

I found suggestion to put my content script file into chrome.tabs.executeScript function but it doesn't work

**UPDATE**

manifest.json

```
{
    "background": {
        "page": "background/background.html",
         "persistent": true
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "img/favicon.png",
        "default_title": "CheapWatcher"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": [
            "lib/jquery.min.js",
            "lib/jquery-ui.min.js",
            "lib/jquery.mousewheel.js",
            "lib/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js",

            "lib/angular.min.js",
            "lib/angular-sanitize.min.js",
            "lib/angular-route.min.js",
            "lib/angular-ui-router.min.js"
        ],
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self",
    "description": "This extension demonstrates injection",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "CheapWatcher",
    "permissions": [
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/",
        "<all_urls>",
        "tabs",
        "cookies"
    ],
    "version": "1.0",
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "views/*.html",
        "src/*.js",
        "css/*.css",
        "lib/*",
        "img/*.png",
        "img/*.gif",
        "img/*.ico",
        "fonts/*.ttf",
        "fonts/*.otf"
    ]
}
```

I'm calling `chrome.tabs.executeScript` from background.js

```
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    if (pageRefreshed === true || pageRefreshed === false && sidebarActive === false && buttonClickedCount === 0 && newTab === false || newTab === true) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "src/injection.js"});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "src/app.js"});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "src/MainController.js"});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "src/LoginController.js"});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "src/ListController.js"});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "src/ErrorController.js"});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "src/NotifyController.js"});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "src/TargetController.js"});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "src/RegisterController.js"});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "src/ResetPassController.js"});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "src/ScrollTargetController.js"});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "src/SetTargetController.js"});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            code: "$('.cheap-watcher' ).animate({ 'right': '0px' }, 'slow');"
        });
        sidebarActive = true;
        buttonClickedCount = 1;
        newTab = false;
        pageRefreshed = false;
    }
    else if (sidebarActive === true && buttonClickedCount > 0) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            code: "$('.cheap-watcher' ).animate({ 'right': '-370px' }, 'slow');"
        });
        sidebarActive = false;
    }
    else if (sidebarActive === false && buttonClickedCount > 0) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            code: "$('.cheap-watcher' ).animate({ 'right': '0px' }, 'slow');"
        });
        sidebarActive = true;
    }
});
```

Yeah I know that this kind of coding is a bad practice, but I'm just trying to make my extension work, but no luck so far. Message passing also doesn't help.

Comment: Not much clear about your question. What do you mean "reload content script without reloading the page"? Do you mean rejecting `injection.js`?

Comment: @HaibaraAi When I reload page, my content script runs and does stuff. When I click browserAction my background script injects nested divs and shows to the user what is injected. The injected screen is empty because my content script ran before I clicked browserAction, so I want to reload my content script so it could run when my injected divs are present

Comment: To avoid race condition, try sending a message from bg script to pageAction, run the code in pageAction only after receiving the message. look at chrome.runtime.sendMessage for more information.

Comment: @NikasŽalias, Basically there are two ways one is programming injection and another is message passing, could you please provide more details how you tried `chrome.tabs.executeScript`? Like where you call it and your `manifest.json`?

Comment: @NikasŽalias, when you are saying not work, what's the error info? `chrome.tabs.executeScript` has a callback parameter if your scripts have dependency on former scripts, you should inject them inside the callback.

Comment: @HaibaraAi I'm not getting any errors at all... Injection.js script works fine, but the rest of the scripts do not work. When I press my browser action I get grey screen and that's it. Yes I will try to call other scripts in callback

Comment: @NikasŽalias, have a try and it would be great if you could minify your code since there are two many scripts injected now and not sure what you want to have a test for.

Comment: @HaibaraAi executing scripts in callbacks didn't helped. I'm testing if my scripts work. After browser action clicked angular should work, but it doesn't. Also I should see some content, but all I see is grey screen. So basically now my extension does not work because my angular does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So everything I did was good, but the only thing I've missed was manually bootstrap my angular module, so I just wrote this code in my SetTargetController.js (because it is the last angular file that is injected)

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```